# This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a public google spreadsheet add-on that returns me this error `This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account.` when I try to add another trigger. I checked and the script does not have any active triggers.
Did someone else had this problem?

I see that there is also an issue posted here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=6108

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313445/this-add-on-has-created-too-many-time-based-triggers-in-this-document-for-this-g)

Answer (score 2):

[Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814143/how-to-get-around-time-trigger-limitations-for-add-ons-in-google-app-script/57820818#57820818) have run into this restrictions as well, but it is documented at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-triggers#restrictions:

> Each add-on can only have one trigger of each type, per user, per document.

Note that during development (before deploying the script as an add-on), this restriction doesn't exist, which may lead to implementing trigger-based algorithms that wouldn't work as add-ons.

Answer (score -2):

Try making a new sheet, (maybe in a different google account), copy the data and script into it manually and see if it still an error. You can later copy it back into your original account.

Comment: The thing is that it works to add a single time-based trigger, but when I try to add other then it throws this error