# This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I get the error as in title -  This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account

When I run the add-on.

The add-on is for creating time triggers. I have created together of 7 triggers in 3 documents.

Now I can't create new trigger in any documents.

ScriptApp.newTrigger("function") 
.timeBased() 
.atHour(5) 
.everyDays(1) 
.create();

Comment: Duplicate of an older question, [This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136855/this-add-on-has-created-too-many-time-based-triggers-in-this-document-for-this-g)

Answer (score 4):

When calling a function that creates a new trigger, it is always a good idea to delete all the existing triggers of the same name inside that same function. You may otherwise end up creating a new trigger each time you run that function.

The other good option is to check for existing trigger and create a new trigger only if none exist.

```
function createTrigger(fnName) {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var triggerExists = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === fnName) {
      triggerExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!triggerExists) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(fnName).timebased().everyHours(1).create;
  } 

}
```

Comment: Can I create more than 1 trigger (per sheet) using an addon published internally in my domain? Awaiting reply Amit

Answer (score 1):

You should only have to run that once to create the trigger. In script editor, go to Edit>All your triggers and you should see all of the triggers for your script. You will see multiple identical triggers created from that newTrigger function. Delete all the duplicates.

[image]